# How do I write tests for a snakemake pipeline?

Tags: snakemake, reproducibility

I've been playing with snakemake, which is really powerful, however, I'd like to create a 'unit test' for the whole pipeline. e.g. a way to call the pipeline that tests that all the rules work together, all the steps complete, etc.

I assumed I could find some guides about how to do this, but I don't find any clear information about how to tests pipelines.

Any advice or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I made a feature request here: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/599

Answer (score 5):

You can run CI on a snakemake workflow when provoding a minimal example dataset. Maybe an example from the snakemake-workflows repo will be helpful: https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-varlociraptor

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do when I want to check whether a program runs from start to finish and produces the expected output on test data. [Here](https://github.com/dariober/fxstat) I used it to test a C program but the idea can be applied also to a snakemake pipeline as in your case.

The idea is pretty simple really: use python's `subprocess` module to run the pipeline then check the results using the `unittest` module (or your favourite unit test package).

For example, save this in `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
import os
import subprocess as sp

class Tester(unittest.TestCase):

    def testPipelineMakesStuff(self):
        # Run the pipeline
        p= sp.Popen('snakemake [some parameters]', shell=True, stdout= sp.PIPE, stderr= sp.PIPE)
        
        # Optionally, get stdout and stderr
        stdout, stderr= p.communicate()

        # Check exits code and other expected output            
        self.assertEqual(0, p.returncode)
        self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile('some.pipeline.output.txt'))

        ...Maybe read some.pipeline.output.txt and check it looks ok

    def testPipelineReturnsWithError(self):
        p= sp.Popen('snakemake [some parameters]', shell=True, stdout= sp.PIPE, stderr= sp.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr= p.communicate()
        self.assertTrue(p.returncode != 0)
        self.assertTrue('Something went wrong' in stderr.decode())
    
    def ...more test cases...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Run this script as:

```
 python test.py
```

and check all tests pass ok. Of course, you can embed `python test.py` in travis or other continuous integration system as I've done [here](https://github.com/dariober/fxstat/blob/master/.travis.yml).